# Django -- I have a small app ready, Should I go on private VPS or Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have my first app, not that big, but it is the first step. (next big one on the way)

Now if I want to put it on my own Linode VPS, I have to configure `mod_python or mod_wsgi,` as well as memcache, Ngix, mySQL or Postgresql, etc. to make it work. If I put it GAE, All I have to do is convert the models to use GAE's API.

What I like about GAE is scaling. (if they can really do it)

Then I'd only worry about developing my apps and doing SEO work on them instead of worrying about load share/balance, cache, db / IO redundancy, etc.

I don't want to do any porting later on. (I have to decide now and stick with it)

So, if you have any experience on this, what do you recommend:

```
1- Use VPS(s) for everthing
2- Use VPS(s) plus Amazon S3
3- Use VPS(s) plus Amazon S3 & SimpleDB
4- Use GAE
```

Also: Would I be able to get away with not having JOIN rights when using the BigTable?

Note: I don't have any spatial need now, but for a location table I might need that later on.

I'd like to know what do you think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's business risk and technical risk.

Business risk is that you might have to move hosts later for some external reason. VPS's, EC2, etc require more upfront investment, but keep you independent. Tools like [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) can help with the configuration effort.

Technical risk is that your application may not be easily implemented on the platform. Since most VPS options allow you to install arbitrary software, they minimize this, again at the cost of more configuration effort on your part. AFAIK, the largest constraint GAE enforces on you is it's difficult to do long running background tasks. (Working without JOINs and other aspects of de-normalized data requires a different way of thinking, but this approach is fairly common in web applications no matter where they run once the SQL database is larger than a single host can support.)

If you can live with both these risks, GAE would appear to save you a substantial amount of effort. If you cannot live with these risks, you should tailor your own environment.

As an aside, I find S3 to be worth it no matter your environment. It's far simpler than ensuring your local server static file storage is reliably backed up, and you never have to worry about capacity. It's best if you use it for data that is uploaded but rarely overwritten or deleted (think facebook photo albums).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to do any porting later on. (I have to decide now and stick with it)

If that's the case, wouldn't you prefer to control deployment from the outset? It could be a great pain to port *back* from GAE later down the line if you hit its limits (whether they be technological limits or simply business decisions by Google that run counter to your plans for the future of your app).

Also configuring mod_wsgi, installing postgres etc. isn't particularly difficult, and you don't have to worry about things like load balancing and db redundancy for a while yet.

If it were me, I'd prefer the long-term certainty of a traditional server over the quick win of GAE. It all depends on your vision for the app, however.

Answer (score 1):

I may be biased, but if you can live with GAE's limitations it really saves you a lot of work and worry about system administration issues (and to some extent scaling) -- plus, it's free as long as your resource consumption is low (basically meaning your traffic is low).

Can you do without joins? I don't know, as I don't know your app -- I'm a SQL fanatic, myself, yet for simple enough needs I haven't found it *too* hard to adapt. As I see it, the main limitation of non-relational DBs is that they're nowhere as nice as relational ones for "ad hoc" queries... you typically have to write a lot of procedural code instead of a nice SELECT or two:-(. But, that's more of a "data mining later" issue than one connected with serving your web app -- probably best solved by regularly bulk-downloading data from the web app's online storage to a "data warehouse" kind of setup, anyway, even if such storage *was* relational in the first place;-).

Answer (score 1):

Before deciding, it might be worth a quick prototype adaptation of your app to GAE. You might run into stoppers that force the decision. Possible stopper issues include

- Your schema doesn't make the transition to BigTable
- You're depending on some C-based library that GAE doesn't support
- You have a few long-running requests that exceed the thresholds that GAE imposes

Comment: Two more to add:  * You need SSL to your.domain  * you need a naked domain, not www.your.domain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the complexity and nature of your model layer, really. If it's complex or tightly bound to the rest of your code, porting is likely to be a significant effort. If it's fairly straightforward, or easy to tear out and replace, I would say go for it.

These days, I mostly write new code for GAE, but the fact that I can simply deploy with a single command has really lowered the barrier I feel towards writing cool new apps. Not having to worry about deployment and hosting is quite liberating.

Answer (score 0):

> All I have to do is convert the models to use GAE's API.

I am sorry, you are totally mistaken.

You also need to rewrite all the `views` code that uses the ORM. There are no joins. So you have to deal with and write a lot of procedural code instead of the nifty SQL that provides U whatever you want.

[Querying is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954796/is-bigtable-slow-or-am-i-dumb). You need to override save method of each model to store additional information of that model which may take a lot of time to compute when need. You also need to work on `memcache` to make the queries fast enough.

And then, Guido has said Django 1.1 is going to be included in a future version of Appengine. I am hoping they will have an out of the box generic ORM to BigTable mapper.

That said, if your app is simple without many joins needed, you could use the appengine patch project to use the current version of django on Appengine. [Here is how.](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/04/develop-twitter-api-application-in-django-and-deploy-on-google-app-engine/#comments)